# Nginx trying to open passengerfile.json which doen't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger-nginx

I am trying to deploy my rails app(API only) using capistrano to the centos server with Nginx and passenger. When I try to hit the rails application, it says
Error opening '/home/user/app/current/Passengerfile.json' for reading: Permission denied (errno=13); This error means that the Nginx worker process (PID 4344, running as UID 984) does not have permission to access this file.

But I don't have passengerfile.json in there and we don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that error was occurring because I was trying to deploy my app through root user. Once I created deploy user and deployed it by that user and added:

```
passenger_user_switching on;
passenger_user deploy;
passenger_group deploy;
```

to the passenger.conf it worked perfectly.

Comment: Where Can I find passnger.conf?

Comment: @PrasathRajasekaran You can find it inside the Nginx path. For me it was inside /etc/nginx/conf.d/passenger.conf

Comment: Do you mean this fine - mod-http-passenger.conf ?

Comment: Yes. For me it was passenger.conf but I think it's the same file.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the below line to your nginx.conf file.

`user deploy`

Replace deploy by your deploy user name

FYI: I followed [these](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/rubygems_rvm/) steps to install passenger (Installing passenger from ruby gems(rvm))

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but I had to comment out user www-data. Question: Could this be an issue in the future? Or is it possible to add multiple users to nginx.conf? Thanks in advance